# SQL output from dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an stupid question about output.
I have an stored procedure that inside is doing a dynamic SQL for checking if there are records in a table, this is the example:

```
SET @sqlLog = 
    'SELECT 1 FROM MyTable 
      WHERE TableName = ''' + @TableName + '''' + '
        AND TheKey = ''' + convert(varchar(50), @LoadGuid) + ''''                                    
EXEC(@sqlLog)
```

After that I'm using @@RowCount to validate if the result is 0 or not.

The problem is that is inside a WHILE and for each row is showing the result in the output window of SQL Management Studio and I don't really want this.
Any idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you even need dynamic SQL for this?, you could do something like the following:

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM MyTable 
            WHERE TableName = @TableName 
            AND TheKey = convert(varchar(50), @LoadGuid))
BEGIN
    -- Your logic here
END
```

Comment: @rgx71 - Not a stupid question at all. If this answer (or some other answer here) correctly addresses your question, please consider to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to know the number of rows that result from the query, try changing the select list to only be `'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable ... '`. This will give you the count as a single result.

Comment: My problem is that I don't want the output during the execution of the stored procedure shows me the result of the count(*)

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @count int

exec sp_executeSql 
    N'set @count = (select count(*) from MyTable where TableName = ''' + @tableName + '''
    and TheKey =  ''' + convert(varchar(50), @LoadGuid) + '''',
    N'@count int output',
    @count = @count output

if @count > 0
    print 'rows exist'
else
    print 'no rows'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the NOCOUNT option:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx for details.

Good luck,

Dave Cherkassky

Comment: This won't help with op's problem

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have it surpress the results of a straight select statement like that.  You are literally telling it to return those results to the calling application, here SSMS, and it is doing so.  SSMS is properly displaying those results.  You have some options as to how you want to display them (results pane or as text, etc.), but I do not know of an option in SSMS to turn it off.

What you could do is use [sp_executesql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) with an output paramater so that instead of requesting any results, you are simply having it put the rowcount in a parameter.  That would look something like:

```
declare @theCount int

SET @sqlLog =       'SELECT @theCount = count(*)  
  FROM MyTable         
  WHERE TableName = ''' + @TableName + '''' + 
  '          AND TheKey = ''' + convert(varchar(50), @LoadGuid) + ''''            

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlLog, N'@theCount int OUTPUT', @theCount=@theCount OUTPUT
```

Then you check whether the value of @theCount is 0 instead of @@Rowcount.